# strange error: Cowardly refusing to pack object with circular reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a prototype method to get nested properties in an object (or return null if not exists).

```
Object.prototype.getNested = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var obj = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) return null;
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return obj;
};
```

So i'm getting this error:

```
uncaughtException: Cowardly refusing to pack object with circular reference getNested
```

What does this error means? I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my guess is this error message is coming from the [msgpack npm module as indicated in the source code here](https://github.com/pgriess/node-msgpack/blob/c9d5fdaa064fa5969a119fa186b091c3f7c60994/test/lib/msgpack.js#L14). What it means is you are trying to serialize an object that refers to itself. Here's me reproducing this error in the node REPL:

```
> var msgpack = require("msgpack");    
> var obj = {};
> obj["me"] = obj;
{ me: [Circular] }
> msgpack.pack(obj);
TypeError: Cowardly refusing to pack object with circular reference
    at Object.pack (/Users/plyons/projects/stackoverflow/node_modules/msgpack/lib/msgpack.js:30:18)
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
```

You need to debug into that stack and see which exact object is getting passed to `msgpack.pack` then you can understand the real root cause. It might just be a matter of when you add `getNested` as a property, make sure to mark it non-enumerable.